# What is the recommended way to update multiple fields of ImmutableJS Record?

Tags: typescript, immutability, record, immutable.js

I have ImmutableJS Record and i want to update multiple fields, what is the recommended way?

I tried withMutations but for some reason the copy i get is empty and i can`t mutate it:

```
const UserRecord = Record({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null, 
  address: {
    city: null, 
    zipCode: null
  }
});

export function createUserRecord(data) {
  return new UserRecord(fromJS(data));
}

let u = createUserRecord({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Don', 
  address: {
    city: 'New York', 
    zipCode: 1111
  }
});

let newU = u.withMutations((uCopy) => {
  // uCopy is empty (with default values)
  uCopy.set('firstName', 'New FirstName');
  uCopy.set('lastName', 'New LastName');
  // uCopy is still empty (not mutated)
});

console.log(u.toJS()); // {firstName: "John", lastName: "Don", address: {city: null, zipCode: null}}
console.log(newU.toJS()); // {firstName: null, lastName: null, address: {city: null, zipCode: null}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've tried it again in a fiddle and it works. The object `u` remains as it was and the new object you get, namely `newU` has the new values for firstName and lastName and the street is still New York 1111

Answer (score 1):

The method `withMutations` doesn't change the object `u`. It returns a mutated object instead, so you need to call it like this

```
let newU = u.withMutations((uCopy) => {
  // uCopy is empty (with default values)
  uCopy.set('firstName', 'New FirstName');
  uCopy.set('lastName', 'New LastName');
  // uCopy is still empty (not mutated)
});
```

---

Take a look at this example in the docs from https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

```
var list1 = Immutable.List.of(1,2,3);
var list2 = list1.withMutations(function (list) {
  list.push(4).push(5).push(6);
});
assert(list1.size === 3);
assert(list2.size === 6);
```

Comment: I have edited the question, please check it again. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I copied over your code to a jsfiddle. The results are - 
`Object { firstName: "John", lastName: "Don", address: Object } 

Object { firstName: "New FirstName", lastName: "New LastName", address: Object }`